# XML response is cutted till 65Kb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I have sitemap generation action like this:

```
def sitemap
  last_model = MyModel.active.last
  if stale?(etag: last_model, last_modified: last_model.created_at.utc)
    @my_models = MyModel.active

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml {render layout: false}
    end
  end
end
```

Its routed in routes.rb: `match '/sitemap.xml' => 'dashboard#sitemap', defaults: {format: :xml}`. I use xml builder as a view template.

I have a strange issue - when I start passenger standalone 3 (compiled with nginx) in production env, I get normal responses with full xml. But after some time I start to get only a part of xml (first 65Kb or less often 16Kb).
I tried to comment stale? condition and even then I have this issue.

What could be the possible fixes? Thanks

Comment: what is your webserver config?

Comment: default, just `passenger start -p 3000 -e production`

Comment: do you serve the project with passenger directly outside?

Comment: yes, directly, without proxies.

Comment: it's probable not the reason issue, but try to serve it with webserver (httpd, nginx) before we go to find another reasons

Comment: thanks, I`ll test it a bit later.

Comment: I`ve localized the problem. Passenger now is starting from ssh console, when I run `passenger start -p 3000 -e production`. If I`ll disconnect from the console and leave passenger working, I`ll get the XML response cutted to 16Kb. All the data after ~16K is lost.

Comment: If you would like passenger this way, use with 'screen'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with starting passenger as a daemon process with:

```
$ passenger start -p 3000 -e production -d
```